# Proving that a diagonalisable and non-invertible matrix must be a zero matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Suppose I have a $n$ x $n$ matrix M that has only an eigenvalue of 0, and is therefore not invertible. If it is known that this matrix is diagonalisable, how would I prove that M must be a zero matrix?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M = S^{-1}DS$ be a diagonalization, so that $D$ is a diagonal matrix. If $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $M$, what values can be on the diagonal of $D$?